# pandas pivot table by week year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, split

I'm new to pandas and I've to generate a pivot table for each week using as source a csv containing records from several years.

I can't figure the right way to filter the dataframe by week. This is how I am doing manually:

```
    fmindate = (df.fecha.astype( 'datetime64[ns]' ) >= pd.to_datetime( "2017-03-01" ))
    fmaxdate = (df.fecha.astype( 'datetime64[ns]' ) <= pd.to_datetime( "2018-01-15" ))

    dffiltered = df[ (fmindate & fmaxdate) ]
    txt = pd.pivot_table(
            dffiltered,
            columns=[ "fecha" ],
            index=[ "org", "tipo", "estado" ],
            values=[ "destination", "time_total", "time_avg" ],
            aggfunc={ "destination": len, "time_total": total_secs_inTimeSerie,
                      "time_avg": mean_secs_inTimeSerie },
            fill_value="", margins=True
    )
    with open(report_name, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write ( txt.to_html() )
```

What would be the right approach?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: But I think you need `df["fecha"] = df["fecha"].dt.weekofyear` add before `pd.pivot_table` and remove filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`weekofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekofyear.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=6, freq='6M')

df = pd.DataFrame({'org':list('aaabbb'),
                   'estado':list('cccbbb'),
                   'destination':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'time_total':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'time_avg':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'fecha':rng,
                   'tipo':list('aaabbb')})


df["fecha"] = df["fecha"].dt.weekofyear
print (df)
   destination estado  fecha org  time_avg  time_total tipo
0            4      c     17   a         1           7    a
1            5      c     44   a         3           8    a
2            4      c     18   a         5           9    a
3            5      b     44   b         7           4    b
4            5      b     18   b         1           2    b
5            4      b     44   b         0           3    b
```

---

```
def total_secs_inTimeSerie(x):
    return x.sum()

def mean_secs_inTimeSerie(x):
    return x.mean()

txt = pd.pivot_table(
            df,
            columns=[ "fecha" ],
            index=[ "org", "tipo", "estado" ],
            values=[ "destination", "time_total", "time_avg" ],
            aggfunc={ "destination": len, "time_total": total_secs_inTimeSerie,
                      "time_avg": mean_secs_inTimeSerie },
            fill_value="", margins=True
    )
```

---

```
print (txt)
                destination               time_avg                           \
fecha                    17   18   44 All       17   18        44       All   
org tipo estado                                                               
a   a    c                1  1.0  1.0   3        1  5.0  3.000000  3.000000   
b   b    b                   1.0  2.0   3           1.0  3.500000  2.666667   
All                       1  2.0  3.0   6        1  3.0  3.333333  2.833333   

                time_total                  
fecha                   17    18    44 All  
org tipo estado                             
a   a    c               7   9.0   8.0  24  
b   b    b                   2.0   7.0   9  
All                      7  11.0  15.0  33
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Found a solution for my problem, shared below.

Comment: I dont downvote your solution, but it is really hard without explanation create your ;)

Comment: Yes, sure, no problem. If want modify my solution, it is good idea - personally I  have no problem. But in future the best is explain more what you need with sample data and expected output. Good luck!

Comment: Just explained the code. Would be nice to upvote my solution. Maybe someone can take advantage of it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And also support you by another upvote ;) Because really hard get points for novice in SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my explanation was not clear enough. From the source csv I need a pivot table exactly like I show, but one of each week on the range of the source records. 
Finally found a soluction, any improve is welcome. Maybe can be useful for someone else:

```
def week_range( date ):
    """ Utility function. Returns start and end dates for a given date (starting Monday) """
    year, week, dow = date.isocalendar()
    if dow == 7:
        start_date = date
    else:
        start_date = date - timedelta( dow )
    end_date = start_date + timedelta( 6 )
    return (start_date, end_date)

# Load and get first date (fecha) in the sorted by date csv file
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
nextDate = df.head(1)
nextDate = pd.to_datetime(nextDate["fecha"].values[0])
continueNextWeek = True

while continueNextWeek:
    # Get week start and end dates for the current date
    datefrom, dateto = week_range( nextDate )
    fmindate = (df.fecha.astype( 'datetime64[ns]' ) >= datefrom )
    fmaxdate = (df.fecha.astype( 'datetime64[ns]' ) <= dateto )

    # Get a by date filtered dataframe
    dfFiltered = df[ (df.tipo == "Saliente") & (fmindate & fmaxdate) ]

    # If there are records for that week, generate pivot table
    if dfFiltered.shape[0]: 
        txt = pd.pivot_table(
                dfFiltered,
                columns=[ "fecha" ],
                index=[ "org", "tipo", "estado" ],
                values=[ "destino", "duracion_total", "duracion_media" ],
                aggfunc={ "destino": len, "duracion_total": total_secs_inTimeSerie, "duracion_media": mean_secs_inTimeSerie },
                fill_value="", margins=True
        )
        # Write it to disk
        report_name = "report-{}-{}.html".format(datefrom.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),dateto.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        with open(os.path.join("out",report_name), "w") as text_file:
            text_file.write ( txt.to_html() )

    # Stop if the week end date is greater than last record in set
    if dateto > df.tail(1)["fecha"].astype( 'datetime64[ns]').values[0]:
        continueNextWeek = False
    else:
        nextDate = dateto + timedelta(1)
```